# Input Special characters to PPTX using docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

I got a special character from ASCII value and created a presentation by inputting that character using docx4j library. If I want to print "£" mark it print with "Â£". Is there a special way to input special characters to the PPT.
I used following code.
       String iChar = new Character((char)163).toString(); 
       t.setTextContent(iChar);

Comment: Note that you can write that string as `String iChar = "\u00A3";`

Answer (score 0):

Please unzip your pptx, and have a look at the content of the slide.  It should contain something like:

```
<a:t>£</a:t>
```

You can create a p containing that with:

```
// Create object for p
CTTextParagraph textparagraph = dmlObjectFactory.createCTTextParagraph(); 
textbody.getP().add( textparagraph); 
    // Create object for r
    CTRegularTextRun regulartextrun = dmlObjectFactory.createCTRegularTextRun(); 
    textparagraph.getEGTextRun().add( regulartextrun); 
        regulartextrun.setT( "£");
```

or by unmarshalling a string.  In either case, you can just provide the £ char directly.

You can generate suitable code using the docx4j webapp at http://webapp.docx4java.org/